# angular ng-bind-html inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Similar questions with

1. [Angularjs: ng-bind-html & ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22445290/angularjs-ng-bind-html-ng-repeat)
2. [Angular ng-bind-html inside a nested ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28867199/angular-ng-bind-html-inside-a-nested-ng-repeat)
3. [Ng-Bind-Html inside ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35464256/ng-bind-html-inside-ng-repeat)

I have this working html code

```
<div class="modal modal-wide fade" id="indexHTML" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">index.html</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

            <pre><code class="language-markup" ng-bind-html="indexHTML"></pre></code>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Since I need to use this code many times, instead of copy pasting, I decided to use ng-repeat

```
<repeat ng-repeat="modal in modals">

    <div class="modal modal-wide fade" id="{{modal.id}}" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">{{modal.fileName}}</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">

                <pre><code class="language-markup" ng-bind-html="{{modal.id}}"></pre></code>

                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</repeat>
```

I got this error that I could not figure out
[image]

Also, I find out that many people suggesting to use $sce.trustAsHtml(), but in my case my ng-bind-html work perfectly with ngSanitize before im trying to use ng-repeat, so do i really to use it to solve my problem?

**Update**

I don't know why but when I don't use the ng-repeat, I need to manually replace "<" with "<" in my controller

```
function getSourceCode(object, property, url) {
    $http.get(url).then(function(response) {
        object[property] = response.data.replace(/</g,"&lt;");
    }).catch(console.error.apply(console));
}
```

But when I change the code to use the ng-repeat, changing ng-bind-html to ng-bind and removing .replace() function in controller should do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why but when I don't use the ng-repeat, I need to manually replace "<" with "<" in my controller

```
function getSourceCode(object, property, url) {
    $http.get(url).then(function(response) {
        object[property] = response.data.replace(/</g,"&lt;");
    }).catch(console.error.apply(console));
}
```

But when I change the code to use the ng-repeat, changing ng-bind-html to ng-bind and removing .replace() function in controller should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

`ng-bind-html` takes an expression. So it should be something like `ng-bind-html="modal.html"`. No `{{}}`.

Comment: I have tried that, but that way it will not referencing to the content of the html. in my case if I use ng-bind instead of ng-bind-html it work perfectly but they will replace the html part for ex "<" to "&lt;"